# snmget wont work, snmpgetnext does

Tags: snmp

I am working on an overview programm for all of our printers (we are a printing company with a huge amount of industry printers).
The only way to communicate with the printers is through SNMP. Since i didnt get any documentation of the SNMP MIB´s (which is pretty poor, cause we using our own built machines) i searched the last few days for any usable OID string, which are working with the result i expect.
The rest was reverse engineering by far.

I found out many useful OID´s and i am nearly finished with the DLL, i am working on (in coop with WinAPI wsnmp32.dll), but now i am stuck on the JobQueue OID´s.

So now to my problem :)
For your info and as an example:
The ID of the JobQueue is 1202 and the Job ID is 5495. If i want to get the pages which should be printed in this job i have to call the OID:
.1.3.6.1.4.1.2699.1.1.1.3.1.1.7.1202.5495

So far so good. If i am doing this with snmpget, i am getting a return of "No Such Instance". But there is definetly an instance.
I know that for sure, cause i am calling snmpgetnext on the instance before (using OID .1.3.6.1.4.1.2699.1.1.1.3.1.1.7.1202.5494), i am getting an integer value of 9002, which is correct, since this is the amount of pages, which have to be printed in this job.
The instance is working and returning a value ... but only if i call snmpgetnext on the instance before. Calling snmpget directly on 5495 wont work.

Is there anything i missunderstand about calling snmpget and so i doing it wrong?
Hope anyone can help me :)

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure the instance is visible in WALK result, but is not accessible via GET operation. There are the possible causes,

- This agent is buggy.
- When WALK was performed, the job was still running, but when GET was performed, the job finished and the row was removed from the table. This table is dynamic, so its content can vary by time.

To confirm which cases you hit, simply do another WALK to see whether that row exists after the GET.

Comment: Thx for your unfriendly answer
Just FYI ... ive done a walk command before and getting this response:
iso.3.6.1.4.1.2699.1.1.1.3.1.1.7.1202.5494 = INTEGER: 9002
iso.3.6.1.4.1.2699.1.1.1.3.1.1.7.1202.5495 = INTEGER: 9002

Comment: 5495 IS the jmJobIndex and 1202 IS the jmGeneralJobSetIndex

Comment: @user2865676, if you have done WALK, why not describe that in your question? That can save everyone's time. Just edited my answer.

Comment: k ... guess its buggy then.

I am working with iReasoning MIB Browser for my reverse engineering.
The getnext and walk does working with this instance and get does not.
After snmpget fails, and doing another walk and/or getnext the instance is still there.

Only answer for me is, that something is buggy :(

Comment: Found out something-> snmpget works with the rownumber. e.g iso.3.6.1.4.1.2699.1.1.1.3.1.1.7.1202.1 gives me the value which jmJobImpressionsPerCopyRequested have for the index combination 1202.4984 (an old job by the way)